# Should we treat "Is it possible to X?" questions as "How do I X?"

Tags: discussion, questions

Often an otherwise reasonable question is poorly written as "Is it possible to", when it's clear that they really want to know "How do I". For example, [Is there any way to seprate strings to substrings we choose? like: sin(log(10))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723817/is-there-any-way-to-seprate-strings-to-substrings-we-choose-like-sinlog10) begins with "is there any way to..." but then includes the author's attempt to solve the problem.

Because of the wording, someone posted a useless comment

> The answer to "Is there a way...?" is usually yes.

In my opinion, it's unfriendly and a waste of time to get so picky about the precise wording, when the intent is perfectly clear. If you really think the wording is a problem, you can edit the question to say what's obviously meant, rather than commenting.

I know the goal is to have well-written questions, but IMHO this doesn't really impact the question quality significantly. The precise form of the question doesn't affect how easy it is to search for it -- these are mostly noise words.

This is probably a duplicate, but when I searched for "Is it possible to", I just got lots of questions asking if it's possible to do various things in SO (i.e. they also asked it this way when they meant "how do I"), not *about* questions in this form. There are also lots of Q's about yes/no questions, but not specifically this type (e.g. "Is my code good?" or "Is this an example of X?").

Comment: This seems like a pretty classic example of an [indirect question](https://prolanguage.co.th/questions-in-english-direct-and-indirect-questions-ep-6/). "_Indirect questions are used to express extreme politeness when asking someone who you do not know an interrogative question._" In this case, the asker appears to be attempting to show politeness by using an indirect question, which feels less demanding than directly asking "how".

Comment: Exactly. Unfortunately too many participants are pedants, and think that this is not a discussion site and such niceties are inappropriate -- they want everyone to say what they mean.